# WSO2 API Manager (WSO2-AM) and Web services addressing (WS-A )

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, ws-addressing

I've a SOAP web services hosted in a Weblogic Server that uses Web service addressing (WS-A). I'm trying to publish it using WSO2 API Manager.

The original request has a complete SOAP header including an Action and MessageID:

```
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
     <wsa:Action>urn:es:cetelem:ws:venta:promociones:services:promocionesService:promocionesService_v03:PromocionesServicePortType:obtenerPromocionesOperacionVndRequest</wsa:Action>
   <wsa:MessageID>uuid:969e636c-067f-4bed-a38a-65f0f81c295d</wsa:MessageID>
</soapenv:Header>
```

But the wso2-am removes the fields Action and MessageID from the SOAP Header before sending to the final endpoint in the Werblogic server. This is an example of the wrong hearder sent by wso2-am
`<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>`

How can I configure wso2-am to keep the SOAP Header sent by the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I added a new sequence mediation extension in `[CARBON-HOME]/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences` to preserve original WS-A headers. The new extension set to true the `PRESERVE_WS_ADDRESSING` property.

Visit https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Generic+Properties .
The code of the new mediator is:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--In">
    <property name="PRESERVE_WS_ADDRESSING" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
</sequence>
```